# Set value column value of the selected row in RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I need to set the value of a particular column of the selected row in my telerik RadGrid.  I have tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
foreach (GridDataItem row in RadGrid1.Items)  
{  
    if (row.Selected)  
    {  
      row["MessageStatus"].Text = myMsg.MessageStatus;  
    break;  
  }  
}  
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text (value) of cells in RadGridView when looping over them in the following way

```
        using (this.radGridView1.DeferRefresh())
        {
            foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in this.radGridView1.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["ColumnUniqueName"].Value = "Some Value";
            }            
        }
```

Hope that helps